# how to Block specific IP to access the wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i was trying to block a specific IP that is sending me a spam links through my contact us page,
i've blocked that ip from .htaccess file but still the same IP send an emails with spam urls through the contact us page

my website is built on wordpress and i'm using firewall as well to block that IP but still getting emails

any advice?

i tried to block that IP by .htaccess file by using Deny from x.xx.xx.xx
and blocked from the hosting by using IP blocker
in addition the firewall plugin

but still the same ip can send or submit the contact form

Comment: FWIW: You should enable a captcha, rather than trying to block (a) bot(s) based on an IP address

Comment: We need to see your complete `.htaccess` file. However, if that IP is blocked as you say then it can't be the same IP that is still sending request? What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> i'm using a firewall as well to block that IP

If you use the Wordfence plugin, you can lock IP addresses "Wordfence->Firewall->Blocking->Block Type -> Create a block rule->IP".

I think that other plugins use similar settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).